# Google visualization - Show legend just in a specific point

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have the chart bellow in my page, but I need to show a legend to line "Meta" only on the first or the last point, as the image bellow.

Is possible to do it?

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);


      function drawVisualization() {
        // Some raw data (not necessarily accurate)
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
         ['Year',  'Anual', 'Mensal', 'Meta'],
         ['2012',   46.17,   ,        52.5],
         ['2013',   45.34,   ,        52.5],
         ['2014',   45.24,   ,        52.5],
         ['2015',   45.05,   ,        52.5],
         ['2016',   46.69,   ,        52.5],
         ['2016/01',   ,        49.4,       52.5],
         ['2016/02',   ,        49.4,       52.5],
         ['2016/03',   ,        49.4,       52.5],
         ['2016/04',   ,        49.4,       52.5],
         ['2016/05',   ,        49.84,       52.5],
         ['2016/06',   ,        45.34,       52.5],
         ['2016/07',   ,        43.94,       52.5],
         ['2016/08',   ,        49.6,       52.5]
      ]);

    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
      view.setColumns([0, 1,
                       { calc: "stringify",
                         sourceColumn: 1,
                         type: "string",
                         role: "annotation" },
                       2, 
                       { calc: "stringify",
                         sourceColumn: 2,
                         type: "string",
                         role: "annotation" },
                       3, 
                       { calc: "stringify",
                         sourceColumn: 3,
                         type: "string",
                         role: "scope" } ]);

    var options = {
      title : 'OEE - KPI LB3',
      vAxis: {title: '%'},
      hAxis: {title: 'Período'},
      seriesType: 'bars',
      series: {
 1: {type: 'line'},
 2: {type: 'line'}}
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(view, options);
  }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
       <div id="chart_div" style="width: 1200px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

I need to show this line as the red or purple line in the image bellow.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i *think* you're referring to placing an **annotation** on the first or last point...

if so, use the `calc` function to only return the annotation for the first row...

```
{
  calc: function (dt, row) {
    if (row === 0) {
      return dt.getFormattedValue(row, 3);
    }
    return null;
  },
  type: 'string',
  role: 'annotation'
}
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    drawVisualization();
    window.addEventListener('resize', drawVisualization, false);
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});

function drawVisualization() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year',   'Anual',  'Mensal', 'Meta'],
    ['2012',   46.17,    ,         52.5],
    ['2013',   45.34,    ,         52.5],
    ['2014',   45.24,    ,         52.5],
    ['2015',   45.05,    ,         52.5],
    ['2016',   46.69,    ,         52.5],
    ['2016/01',    ,         49.4,       52.5],
    ['2016/02',    ,         49.4,       52.5],
    ['2016/03',    ,         49.4,       52.5],
    ['2016/04',    ,         49.4,       52.5],
    ['2016/05',    ,         49.84,        52.5],
    ['2016/06',    ,         45.34,        52.5],
    ['2016/07',    ,         43.94,        52.5],
    ['2016/08',    ,         49.6,       52.5]
  ]);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1,
    {
      calc: 'stringify',
      sourceColumn: 1,
      type: 'string',
      role: 'annotation'
    },
    2,
    {
      calc: 'stringify',
      sourceColumn: 2,
      type: 'string',
      role: 'annotation'
    },
    3,
    {
      calc: function (dt, row) {
        if (row === 0) {
          return dt.getFormattedValue(row, 3);
        }
        return null;
      },
      type: 'string',
      role: 'annotation'
    }
  ]);

  var options = {
    title : 'OEE - KPI LB3',
    vAxis: {title: '%'},
    hAxis: {title: 'Período'},
    seriesType: 'bars',
    series: {
      1: {
        color: 'green',
        type: 'line'
      },
      2: {
        color: 'red',
        type: 'line'
      }
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(view, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot for the help.